# How to prevent phone number being searched online?

Tags: account-security, phone

Recently, read an article about phone number being used to hack into one's account.
[NYTIMES-Phone hacking](https://nyti.ms/2P8kKZ4)

What needs to be done to prevent my phone number being searched? (Return invalid hyperlinks instead of providing all info).

Comment: You want to cleanse the Internet of all data relating to your phone number and manipulate when gets returned? That's simply not possible.

Comment: @schroeder he might be asking about ways to improve his digital footprint.

Comment: @VipulNair then that needs to be clarified. Although I'm not sure what control someone has over phone numbers databases.

Comment: @schroeder Did you read the article?It was quite a bit of OSINT.Do you know how the researcher did it?I am curious

Comment: @VipulNair I did read the article. The OSINT tagged public databases. Not social media, not services that the person might have used, but independently created and maintained databases. That's not something that falls under "digital footprint".

Comment: I have registered under do not call registry. What else needs to be done?